# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'mockBackend.expectPost(

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to unit test an angularjs controller with Karma, and jasmine.

Here is my test suite:

```
describe('Controllers', function(){
    var $scope, ctrl;
    beforeEach(module('curriculumModule'));
    describe('CreateCurriculumCtrl', function(){
        var mockBackend, location;
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_, $location){
            mockBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            location = $location;
             $scope = $rootScope.$new();
             ctrl = $controller('CreateCurriculumCtrl', {
                    $scope: $scope
             });
        }));

        it('should save the curriculum', function(){
            mockBackend.expectPost('bignibou/curriculum/new');
            $scope.saveCurriculum();
            mockBackend.flush();
            expect(location.path()).toEqual("/");
        });

    });
});
```

Here is the output of karma start:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux) Controllers CreateCurriculumCtrl should save the curriculum FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'mockBackend.expectPost('bignibou/curriculum/new')')
        at /home/julien/Documents/projects/site-garde-enfants/bignibou/karma/test/spec/curriculum.test.js:16
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.203 secs / 0.023 secs)
```

I don't understand why I get this error as I have correctly included the angular-mock.js file in my karma conf:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
   '../src/main/webapp/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js',
   '../src/main/webapp/js/libs/angular.js',
   '../src/main/webapp/js/libs/bootstrap.js',
   '../src/main/webapp/js/plugins/angularui.select2.js',
   'test/vendor/angular-mocks.js',

  '../src/main/webapp/js/custom/curriculum.js',
  'test/spec/curriculum.test.js'      
],
```

Can anyone please help?

**edit**: here is my controller:

```
function CreateCurriculumCtrl($scope, $http, $location, select2Options){

    $scope.formData={};

    $scope.select2Options = select2Options; 

    $scope.saveCurriculum = function(){
        $http.post('bignibou/curriculum/new', $scope.formData).success(function(data) {
            if(data.status=="OK"){}
            if(data.status=="KO"){}
            $location.path("/");
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing line 16

from

```
mockBackend.expectPost('bignibou/curriculum/new');
```

to

```
mockBackend.expect('POST','bignibou/curriculum/new').respond({});
```

somehow fixed the issue...

**edit**: `expectPOST` would have worked too... Just a typo: notice the case I used...

Answer (score 1):

Likely your situation will be similar to:

```
var a = {};
a.b();
```

`a.b` is undefined, trying to call it will give you that error.

Line 16 here is `$scope.saveCurriculum()`, is `$scope.saveCurriculum` undefined?

Comment: Actually I think you are right:  mockBackend seems to be a function and not a object on which I can call a function... a console.log of mockBackend gives this: `function $httpBackend(method, url, data, callback, headers) { ... }`

Comment: Line 16 is this one:    `mockBackend.expectPost('bignibou/curriculum/new');`